# How to bind One group header with the Details section

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'm working on designing a crystal report. I need to display like two tables on one page. where data is coming from a single query.

Ex:
Table 1 columns are:

> |Item No | Item Name | Date | Qtty Sold | Selling Price |

Table 2 columns are:

> Item No | Item Details | RemainingQtty |

Table 1 has 30 rows and table 2 has 5 rows

Can someone help me out how to achieve this?

Many thanks,

Actually i created 2 groups and 2 details section.But not getting how to bind them together

Comment: How are the two tables related?

Answer (score 0):

If you create groups in report then you can't achieve the table format, If you need table format then go for using sub report.

create table 1 in first sub report and table 2 in second sub report.

now you can place those in detail or group as per your requirement.